# Zeros rows returned from ADO Recordset

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ado, recordset

I'm trying to get data from a SQL Server table into an ADO Recordset using the below code. Everything works fine with no errors, but I always get a record count of -1. I've confirmed that the database name and table are correct. If I use SSMS I can see that there is data in the table.

What am I missing here?

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rsCount As Integer

cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=Server1;DataBase=Database1;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
cn.Open

Call rs.Open("Select * from table1", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic)

rsCount = rs.RecordCount
```

Comment: getting `-1` as a return value indicates something didn't work...

Comment: Replace `adOpenDynamic` with `adOpenStatic` and let me know what happen.

Comment: I've never prefaced it with `Call` - that may be throwing things.

Comment: @MaciejLos adOpenStatic is the winner!!!  Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @jradich1234, I'm glad i can help. Please, accept my answer as solution ;)

Comment: @FreeMan `Call` serves no purpose, it's just a deprecated syntax for making a procedure call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i mentioned in a comment to the question, replace `adOpenDynamic` with `adOpenStatic` and you should get proper recordcount.

> The use of the ADO Recordset's `.RecordCount` property requires either
>   the use of:
>
> ```
> 1. Static or Keyset server-side cursors or
> 2. A client-side cursor (which returns a Static cursor)
> ```

---

> The `RecordCount` property will return `-1` for a forward-only cursor; the
>   actual count for a static or keyset cursor; and either `-1` or the
>   actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on the data source.

More details [here](http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/recordcounterror.asp) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)!